# pdfliteral stroke shape after transformation

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Is it possible to modify coordinates in PDF while keeping the stroke square-shaped?

My problem is the following. If I use code like this:

```
\pdfliteral{q
0.5 w 
1 0 0 3 0 0 cm
0  0 m
0   20 l
50  20 l
0   0  l
S
Q
}
```

then the resulting image

[image]

does not look very aesthetic since the brush is shaped as a 1×3 rectangle instead of a square, so the lines are of different thickness. Is it possible to fix it somehow?

An obvious solution is not to use such a transformation of course. But since TeX does not provide easy tools to perform rational arithmetics, I thought that using transformation in PDF would be more elegant.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you provide a working example that demonstrates the issue, rather than just a snippet of code?

Comment: Well, the code _is_ a working example. Just add **\bye** to the end and run with pdftex. I've added the resulting image.

Comment: I guess it is, if you add `\bye` to the end.  At first, I failed to realize it was pdftex, but I see you do tag it as such.

Comment: @Daniel The PDF Reference v1.7 (sec. 5.3.2, sub title _Line Width_) says "If the CTM (current transformation matrix, which is changed by operator `cm` in your example) specifies scaling by different factors in the horizontal and vertical dimensions, the thickness of stroked lines in device space will vary according to their orientation." Hence it is `1 0 0 3 0 0 cm` that changes the line width. Maybe you need to pre-compute the transformed coordinates used in `xpos ypos l` (lineto operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpTeX (OPmac macros for LuaTeX) supports arithmetic in `\pdfliteral` argument. Your example should look like:

```
\pdfliteral{q
0.5 w 
0  0 m
0  \_expr{3*20} l
50 \_expr{3*20} l
0   0  l
S
Q
}
```

Answer (score 2):

tikz handles this quite fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pdfliteral{q
0.5 w
1 0 0 3 0 0 cm
0  0 m
0   20 l
50  20 l
0   0  l
S
Q
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=3cm]
  \draw (0,0)--(0,2)--(5,2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the tikz package. Using PGF instead of pdfliteral is probably a good idea. Anyway, I am still interested in answering the former question, but I am afraid that answer is no, it is not possible to fix the issue in some easy way.